# iOS Can't Get PDF to Appear in UIWebView

Tags: ios, pdf, uiwebview

I'm having issues displaying a PDF in a UIWebView - something that should be really trivial (even for me beginner level). However I'm not seeing anything.

I have a UIWebView correctly connected as an IBOutlet, then in the viewDidLoad, i have the following code:

```
NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"/Users/tom........../PDF_6.pdf"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
[_pdfWebView loadRequest:request];
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong??

Thanks.

(Apologies if this is a really duplicated question i just can't find the answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it seems you want to load the PDF from a file, you need to create a file URL:

```
NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/Users/tom........../PDF_6.pdf"];
```

BTW - that path is only going to work in the simulator, not on a real iOS device.

Comment: Thanks!! I really need to pay more attention !

Comment: Haha no worries mate - was waiting for the 6 mins :)